# Center content with fixed background

Tags: html, css

I want to center all the content of a website with a fullscreen background even when resized with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + **scroll mouse button** on windows.

Website exemple : http://www.benzinga.com/

If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and use the *scroll button on your mouse*, you will see that the background of the header stays full screen, but the content stays centered.

Is it possible to do that only with HTML and CSS?

Can you show me how?

Comment: Please post the code you want us to examine in the question itself; we shouldn't have to go to external sites to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are going for.  The width for the content div should be in terms of `px` rather than `%` in order for it to properly zoom.

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    body {
        background:url('http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg');
        background-size:cover;
    }
    #content {
        background-color:red;
        width:1000px;
        height:500px;
        margin:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use Bootstrap's container div.

Once you include [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download),

Simply use:

```
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>
```

The content will stay within that, in the center of the page, very similarly to she site you linked, even when you zoom in.